# Lookup table for 'industry compatible' and the default 'industry incompatible' shortcuts?

Tags: shortcut

I am having a horrid time trying to do the donut tutorial because there's no lookup table for 'industry compatible' shortcuts vs the standard ones.

Unfortunately 'Just use the Blender default shortcuts' is not an option when I also have to use several other applications that orbit-like-Maya (years of muscle memory) and have stuff like 'press f to focus' as defaults that I normally don't have to think about.

The donut guy says something like 'press shift A to get this menu' but doesn't say what it's called, so I can't look up what it is in the shortcuts list and switching between 'industry compatible' and the default shortcuts to look up what the tool is called is driving me loopy.

Where can I find a table that says 'Tool name, Blender shortcut, Industry Compatible shortcut'?
Does it exist?
If not, how would I go about making it?

Comment: Hello ! I don't think there is an built-in way to have that information. Usually most if not all edit or object mode operations can be accessed in the menu bar on the top of the 3D viewport, it may be beneficial to know where to find things there before learning the shortcuts. You can also find operations by name using F3 and typing it out. In both cases the shortcut is usually noted besides the operator field

Comment: That'd be ideal but the Donut Guy only says what shortcuts to press, not what the names are so I can't reverse-lookup what the thing is called! 
Catch 22